# Installing ClamAV from Source on Linux

Tags: installation, centos, clamav

If I install ClamAV on Centos using yum, I have a directory with configuration called /etc/clamd.d.  I can then follow a configuration tutorial such as this one:

https://www.golinuxcloud.com/steps-install-configure-clamav-antivirus-centos-linux/

If I follow the ClamAV instructions for building from source located here:

https://www.clamav.net/documents/installation-on-redhat-and-centos-linux-distributions

When I'm done, I don't have /etc/clamd.d.  Why not?

I'm creating a Dockerfile to install with.  Here's the Dockerfile

```
FROM centos:8

COPY clamav-0.102.3.tar /tmp

RUN yum -y update && \
    yum groupinstall "Development Tools" -y && \
    yum install openssl openssl-devel libcurl-devel zlib-devel libpng-devel libxml2-devel bzip2-devel pcre2-devel ncurses-devel  -y && \
    yum install valgrind check check-devel -y && \
    cd /tmp && \
    tar -xf clamav-0.102.3.tar && cd clamav-0.102.3 && \
    ./configure --enable-check && \
    ./configure --sysconfdir=/etc && \
    make -j2 && \
    make check && \
    make install && \
    ls /etc/clamd.d (this fails)
```

Answer (score -1):

The ClamAV RPM packages in EPEL 8 use more build-time options and perform more build- and run-time customizations in general (compared to your minimalistic example), see the [spec file](https://src.fedoraproject.org/rpms/clamav/blob/master/f/clamav.spec) for how this is achieved in detail.

The question however is why you don't simply use the existing ClamAV RPM packages in EPEL 8, given you referred to EPEL 7 installation instructions before.